# I have a ListNode class from which I'm trying to create some sort of singlelinkedlist

Tags: java

```java
public class leetCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ListNode two = new ListNode(4);
        ListNode one = new ListNode(3, two);
        ListNode l1 = new ListNode(2, one);

        ListNode twoB = new ListNode(4);
        ListNode oneB = new ListNode(6, twoB);
        ListNode l2 = new ListNode(5, oneB);

        addTwoNumbers(l1, l2);
    }

    public static void addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {

        List<Integer> list_L2 = new ArrayList<>();
        //243
        //564
        list_L2.add(getInListNode(l1));
    }

    public static int getInListNode(ListNode L) {

        if (L.next == null) {
            return L.val;
        } else {
            List<Integer> list_L3 = new ArrayList<>();
            list_L3.add(L.next.val);
            return getInListNode(L.next);
        }
    }
}


class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;

    ListNode() {
    }

    ListNode(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    ListNode(int val, ListNode next) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(String.valueOf(val).toCharArray());
    }
}
```

Each node in this list is a ListNode object that has 'val' 'and' next properties and 'next' is another ListNode object. I want to get all the values (val) from this custom list and add them to ArrayList (list_L3), I wrote some basic recursion method (getInListNode(ListNode L)) but the problem is that while it will only return value from the last node in the list, I can get access to other values and add them to ArrayList but obviously everytime recursive method is being called upon, given the place I initialized it, ArraList (list_L3) will always be initialized again. I know I could initialize ArrayList as a class field and have all values for each node added to the list_L3 the way I want them but the thing is that there can be no class fields only methods in this excercise. Is there a way I can make my recurssion method go through each node,  take 'val' and add it to the ArrayList which will be somehow visible to addTwoNumbers() method without being a class field or make getInListNode(ListNode L) return an ArrayList filled with 'val's'?

Comment: You could modify your recursive function to take list_l3 as a parameter and instantiate list_l3 in `addTwoNumbers` to use it in that function, this way you wouldn't be reinstantiating it in the other function; if you're allowed to do that.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you expect these methods to do so it is difficult to suggest how to modify them.  You seem to not understand variable scope.

Comment: I want getInListNode() to return or somehow fill an ArrayList with values from each node, i know that a variable initailized  inside a method exist only in that method as long as the method is working and that was exactly the problem I had beacause I didnt want to use class fields that I know are not independent on methods, but an advice by Alias Cartellano resolved that problem

Comment: Thanks @AliasCartellano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make this a smaller question. Why is getInListNode(ListNode L) not working as expected?

In the else section of the method, list_L3 is created and L.next.val is added to it. It does not affect what is getting returned to the caller. To solve this, you can add all of what the recursive call returns to list_L3 before returning it.

Also getinListNode should return a list, not just an integer.

Something like

```
getInListNode(ListNode L) {
if (L.next is null) {
    return L.val;
} else {
    list_L3 = new list()
    list_L3.add(L.next.val)
    list_L3.addAll(getInListNode(L.next))
    return list_L3
}
}
```

This probably has more bugs that need to be taken care of, but this should probably get you unblocked.